# Maximum number of intersections possible for the group of parallel lines?

Tags: combinatorics, induction, contest-math

Suppose we have $x_1$ lines on a plane parallel in one direction ,$x_2$ lines parallel in another direction, $\cdots$,$x_{10}$ lines parallel in another direction. If $x_i$=$i$ for $i$ $\in${$1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10$} then what is the maximum possible number of intersections of these lines?

$My$ $approach$ - I tried to break the problem into sub cases.
To get the maximum number of intersections we have to consider the non-degenerate cases .

$i=\color{red}1$ $\rightarrow$ #$(intersections)=\color{red}0,$

$i=\color{blue}2$ $\rightarrow$#$(intersections)=\color{blue}2,$

$i=\color{green}3$ $\rightarrow$#$(intersections)=\color{blue}2+\color{green}{3(1+2)},$
$$\vdots$$

So generally , we can see, for eg- if $x_{i}=4$, then we have $1$ straight line, $\color{blue}2$ parallel lines different in direction from the previous one , $\color{green}3$ parallel lines different in direction from all the previous lines.

Now for any new line $\color{brown}L$ which is not parallel to the previous lines , it will intersect the 1st parallel line in one point, two 2nd parallel lines in $\color{blue}2$ points and third parallel lines in $\color{green}3$ points. So for four points we get $\color{purple}4(1+\color{blue}2+\color{green}3)$. The collective number of intersections can be given by adding up the previous number of intersections . What I get is that the general sum for $x_{i}=n$ we have $$2+3(1+2)+4(1+2+3)+\ldots+n(1+\ldots+(n-1))$$ many intersections . Can anyone verify this? And are there in methods in competitive high school maths which can solve this problem in more elegant and simple way? Thank you.

Comment: [A related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1404821/11619). A different goal, but I think you may benefit from looking at it. Observe that your problem does not specify that no three or more lines meet at the same point. Wonder if that changes things...

Comment: But it is given that we have to find the maximum number of intersections so I guess we have to relax the degenerate cases in the given problem.

Comment: Correct (+1). I think that the maximum is achieved exactly when no three lines meet at the same point. I leave it to you to figure out what the maximum is. And also to justify that the maximal situation (where no pairs of lines go to waste that way) can be realized by some configuration of lines. Good luck!